# How to fix chart looking blurry in ChartJS?

Tags: javascript, chart.js, momentjs, data-visualization

I made a chart with ChartJS using the following configuration

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
            labels: labels,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Voltage Fluctuation',
                data: data,
                borderWidth: 1,

                fill: false,
            }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: 'time',
                    time: {
                        unit: 'minute',
                        displayFormats: {
                            hour: 'HH:mm:ss'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            },
        }
    });
```

The chart was fed 800 data points and it's quite blurry.[image: ChartJS blurry]
Is there any way I can change the configuration so that the line is continuous and sharp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is **not** blurry. It just looks blurry, as you have large number of data and the data-point circles are overlapping.

One way you can resolve this is by setting the **`pointRadius`** property to **`0`** for your dataset like so :

```
...
datasets: [{
   label: 'Voltage Fluctuation',
   data: data,
   borderWidth: 1,
   fill: false,
   pointRadius: 0  //<- set this
}]
...
```

That will remove those data-point circles.

Comment: Thanks . I set it to 0.3 now and it looks much better than the previous iteration but the color is a bit light. Something to make it pure black line?

Comment: set `pointBorderColor`/`pointBackgroundColor` to `black` for dataset.